# update query for sha2 256 in SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm migrating from mysql to ms sql server,
i was using this query when i used mysql.

```
UPDATE users SET user_password = sha2('test', 256);
```

i'm trying to use this query on mysql server, it returns success query.

```
UPDATE users SET user_password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'test');
```

but when i tried to login using this password it keeps returning wrong password.

Please kindly point out where's my mistake and how can i fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run the update script in management studio?

Comment: @StephenReindl yes, i run the update through the management studio

Comment: Can you please show us the hash that is being set as the new hash in the database?

Comment: @Matt i solved the problem, i'll post it rightaway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently solve this when stumbled some links on google, here's the script.

```
UPDATE users SET usr_password = lower(CONVERT(varchar(max), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'test'), 2));
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for anyone who helped.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually a funny one we've stumbled over some time ago. SQL Management Studio is using UTF-16 as the user's character encoding. If you pass a string directly to `HASHBYTES`, "test" seems to be interpreted as `"t\0e\0s\0t\0"`. If you pass a variable, the parameter is interpreted correctly:

```
DECLARE @tst as NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @tst = 'test';

SELECT @tst, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'test') as "UTF16", 
       HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @tst) as "UTF8"
```

results in

```
UTF16 = '0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08'
UTF8 = '0xFE520676B1A1D93DABAB2319EEA03674F3632EAEEB163D1E88244F5EB1DE10EB'
```

Comment: found a discrepancy in hash value and  above was the cause between utf-8 and utf-16. The  external tool writing to the sql server was using utf-8